# WebBrowser "Can’t connect securely to this page"

Tags: c#, .net

> Can’t connect securely to this page
>   This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening, try contacting the website’s owner."

Trying to view a site with an expired SSL certificate that also has an incorrect web address. How can this be fixed?(I can't make a "working" certificate and use that)

Comment: As well as posting some code, you should explain a few more things here.  Such as, what browser you're using, where the website is hosted, and what you're trying to accomplish.  If this is a public facing website, you likely won't get rid of that error unless they get a valid certificate.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a public facing website, since I'm asking about how can you fix this in C#. The web browser I'm using is the C# WebBrowser component, which is based on IE. There's no point posting any code because I basically don't have any. I just have InitializeComponent();

Comment: The reason I ask about the public facing website is that you can generate a self signed certificate to circumvent the expired certificate if you're running the host from a server you control.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have too much control over the server, because it is a management interface for a Dell PowerEdge 1850, and if I would use a self-signed certificate then the browser would still complain about outdated TLS settings

Comment: @MátéVarga - were you able to solve this?